# Creando API Rest c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estoy realizando un API Rest en c#,me conecte con la BBDD por EF, se construyeron las clases por defecto y como estan relacionadas por un FK cuando realizo el GET me las trae construyendo el siguiente JSON

```
[
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": {
        "id": "5a12ed57c7c51d0b6a8de9c5",
        "company": "COMPANY_NAME",
        "tenant": "5b44ed57d7c33d7b1a8d3015",
        "units": [
            {
                "imei": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "serialNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "stock": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "model": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "warehouse": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "refType": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "refId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "shippingInfo": {
            "nombres": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "apellidoPaterno": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "apellidoMaterno": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "rut": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "direccion": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "comuna": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "tel": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "xxxxxxx",
            "marca": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "modelo": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "vin": "xxxxxxx",
            "patente": "xxxxx",
            "poliza": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "fechaEmision": "2019-08-20T00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

]

Pero yo quisiera que no me los traiga en 1 arreglo inicial ya que el GET y el POST solo deben traer 1 registro por cada llamada por lo que debería ser asi.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": {
        "id": "5a12ed57c7c51d0b6a8de9c5",
        "company": "COMPANY_NAME",
        "tenant": "5b44ed57d7c33d7b1a8d3015",
        "units": [
            {
                "imei": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "serialNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "stock": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "model": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "warehouse": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "refType": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "refId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "shippingInfo": {
            "nombres": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "apellidoPaterno": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "apellidoMaterno": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "rut": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "direccion": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "comuna": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "tel": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "xxxxxxx",
            "marca": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "modelo": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "vin": "xxxxxxx",
            "patente": "xxxxx",
            "poliza": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "fechaEmision": "2019-08-20T00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

He leido que es un rootObject pero no logro encontrar como podría hacer para quitarle el arreglo ya que el posicionamiento lo obtuve cambiando las posiciones con [JsonProperty(Order = X)] . Actualmente mi metodo GEt es este.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<status_tk> Get()
    {
        var listado = BD.status_tk.ToList();

        return listado;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví , estaba confundiendo el concepto, para el GET regular me tiene que mostrar como arreglo ya que puede recibir mas de 1 registro, en el GET/{id} no es así y tampoco en el POST ya que solo recibe 1 rspta por interacción.